# Unable to retrieve archive messages from openfire

Tags: openfire

i have configured *Enable Message Auditing* in server.

**This is the stanza which I have passed to Openfire Server**

```
<body rid='754080999' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' sid='8e08a428'><iq id='zob_5' type='get' xmlns='jabber:client'><list with='sampath@sampath.efycaci.com/js' start='2013-12-20T11:21:46Z' xmlns='urn:xmpp:archive'><set xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'><before/><max>2</max></set></list></iq></body>
```

**This is the result which I received from server**

```
<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'>
 <iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="error" id="zob_5" to="arun@sampath.efycaci.com/js">
      <list xmlns="urn:xmpp:archive" with="sampath@sampath.efycaci.com/js" start="2013-12-20T11:21:46Z">
           <set xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm"><before/>
                <max>2</max>
           </set>
      </list>
       <error code="503" type="cancel">
           <service-unavailable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>
      </error>
 </iq>
```

I Unable to retrieve archive messages from openfire. Please help to fix this.

I am using Openfire 3.8.2.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[getSearchForm returns null when using UserSearch in XMPP with aSmack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910219/getsearchform-returns-null-when-using-usersearch-in-xmpp-with-asmack?lq=1) this link would help . try to add the  configure(ProviderManager pm) function into your project